# Bokeh, select interactivle multiple datasets for plotting

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I am new to using Bokeh.

I have data which roughly looks like that

```
date    names   numbers
2016    var1 62
2012    var2 82
2014    var1 118
2015    var2 69852
2012    var3 167
2016    var1 2266
2011    var1 88282
2015    var3 6307
...
```

I use a Bokeh script to plot the data and from a dropdown menu I can select for which names (var1, var2, ...) to to plot the data.

The script is based on this example: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/weather and looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select
from bokeh.plotting import figure


def get_dataset(src, name):
    df = src[src.names == name].copy()
    del df['names']
    df = df.set_index(['date'])
    df.sort_index(inplace=True)
    return ColumnDataSource(data=df)


def make_plot(source, title):
    plot = figure(plot_width=800, tools="", toolbar_location=None)
    plot.title.text = title
    plot.line(x='date', y='numbers', source=source, legend="Record")
    return plot


def update_plot(attrname, old, new):
    ver = vselect.value
    plot.title.text = "xxx"
    src = get_dataset(df, ver)
    source.date.update(src.date)


df = pd.read_csv('data/test_data.csv', delimiter='\t')
ver = 'aps'

cc = df['names'].unique()

vselect = Select(value=ver, title='VER', options=sorted((cc)))

source = get_dataset(df, ver)
plot = make_plot(source, "xxx")

vselect.on_change('value', update_plot)
controls = column(vselect)

curdoc().add_root(row(plot, controls))
```

This works fine, but I would like to allow now to select multiple names (e.g var1 and var2) to be selected to plot them in the same plot for easy comparison. 
However, I have no idea how to go about this.

Comment: You could change your approach and plot everything from the start while using an interactive legend to trigger visibility.

Answer (score 0):

(Potential) cleanup on aisle 47434701.  Looks like Bokeh has a [MultiSelect](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/widgets.inputs.html?highlight=multiselect#bokeh.models.widgets.inputs.MultiSelect) method that might be useful in this situation.  I presume it wasn't available at the original time of question.